# How to switch to else statement if spinner value is different than first spinner item?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have if statement where I am checking if the values are present or not. if the values are present then perform calculation, else - print out on the screen that user needs to fill out all fields. 
I have it working for weight, height and age which are text fields where user enter the values. But i am struggling to make it work with spinner values. My spinner has define list in xml and is showing the first item that is "Gender" and second spinner showing its first item which is " Activity Level". 
here is how I tried:

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if(adapterView == Gspinner)
    {
        //get dropdown label from gender spinner
        genderCh = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    }
    else if(adapterView == Aspinner)
    {
        //get dropdown label from activity spinner
        ActvCh = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    }
}

//If nothing is selected, do nothing.
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
genderCh = "Gender";
ActvCh = "Activity Level";
}

// Create Calculator function to calculate all values
public void CalculateBMR(View v) {
    String heightStr = height.getText().toString();
    String weightStr = weight.getText().toString();
    String genStr = genderCh;
    String ageStr = age.getText().toString();
    String actvStr = ActvCh;

    // if statement to execute if all required values are present
    if (heightStr != null && !"".equals(heightStr)&& weightStr != null && !"".equals(weightStr) && ageStr != null && !"".equals(ageStr) && genStr != "Gender" && !"".equals(genStr) && actvStr != "Activity Level" && !"".equals(actvStr)){
        double heightValue = Double.parseDouble(heightStr);
        double weightValue = Double.parseDouble(weightStr);
        double ageValue = Double.parseDouble(ageStr);
        // IF statement to provide calculation based on Male gender and one out of 3 level of activity
        if (genStr .equals("Male"))
        {
            double bmr = Math.round((((weightValue / 2.2046) * 10) + (6.25 * (heightValue * 30.48)) - (5 * ageValue) + 5) * 100);
            double bmrr = bmr / 100;
            result1.setText("YOUR BMR IS: " + bmrr);
            if (actvStr .equals("Light"))
            {
                double dtee = Math.round((bmrr * 1.53) * 100);
                result2.setText("YOUR DTEE IS: " + dtee / 100);
            }
            else if (actvStr .equals("Moderate"))
            {
                double dtee = Math.round((bmrr * 1.76) * 100);
                result2.setText("YOUR DTEE IS: " + dtee / 100);
            }
            else if (actvStr .equals("Vigorous"))
            {
                double dtee = Math.round((bmrr * 2.25) * 100);
                result2.setText("YOUR DTEE IS: " + dtee / 100);
            }

        }
        // IF statement to provide calculation based on Female gender and one out of 3 level of activity
        else if (genStr .equals("Female"))
        {
            double bmr = Math.round((((weightValue / 2.2046) * 10) + (6.25 * (heightValue * 30.48)) - (5 * ageValue) - 161) * 100);
            double bmrr = bmr / 100;
            result1.setText("YOUR BMR IS: " + bmrr);
            if (actvStr .equals("Light"))
            {
                double dtee = Math.round((bmrr * 1.53) * 100);
                result2.setText("YOUR DTEE IS: " + dtee / 100);
            }
            else if (actvStr .equals("Moderate"))
            {
                double dtee = Math.round((bmrr * 1.76) * 100);
                result2.setText("YOUR DTEE IS: " + dtee / 100);
            }
            else if (actvStr .equals("Vigorous"))
            {
                double dtee = Math.round((bmrr * 2.25) * 100);
                result2.setText("YOUR DTEE IS: " + dtee / 100);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill out all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Any idea what i need to adjust within if statment where I am checking for spinner values to be different than first value?

```
genStr != "Gender" && !"".equals(genStr) && actvStr != "Activity Level" && !"".equals(actvStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set an `OnItemSelectedListener` for your spinners and run a check on the item selected. The first item listed has the value '0' so you just need to check it's anything else.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner;

int spinnerPosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    spinnerPosition = 0; // A good idea to initialise this variable to 0 in case
                         // an item isn't selected before your check is run
                         // else you'll run a check on un-initialised int

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            spinnerPosition = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
}

//something like this. And then you can add a check for `spinnerPosition != 0`


if (hieghtSpinnerPos == 0 || weightSpinnerPos == 0 || genSpinnerPos == 0 || ageSpinnerPos == 0 || actvSpinnerPos == 0) {

    Toast....fill all fields

} else {
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead the comparison Operator `==` use `instanceof`

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    if(adapterView instanceof Gspinner)
    {
        //get dropdown label from gender spinner
        genderCh = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    }
    else if(adapterView instanceof Aspinner)
    {
        //get dropdown label from activity spinner
        ActvCh = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    }
}
```